# How can I use the layout and twoside options of the geometry package?

Tags: margins, double-sided, paper-size, geometry

When I use the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) (2010/09/12 v5.6) for a `twoside` document with one paper size (e.g. A4) and another layout size (e.g. A5), I had expected that I could print a page, turn the paper, print the other side, and cut the paper according to the crop marks. For this to work the crop marks at both sides of the sheet of paper must lay at the same position, i.e. if the first side is placed at the left of the sheet of paper,
the second one must be placed at the right side. But the MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[twoside,a4paper,layout=a5paper,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\begin{document}
1
\newpage
2
\end{document}
```

and pdfLaTeX result into

[image: pdfLaTeX MWE.tex]

What must I change to get "twoside-mode"?

Comment: have you tried `asymmetric=true`?

Comment: Can't find any option in the code. Maybe manually set layouthoffset dependent on oddness? Ok, doesnt solve the crop mark problem...

Comment: It's probably easier to use the [crop](http://ctan.org/pkg/crop) package here.

Comment: @cmhughes: `asymmetric=true` changes the content inside of the layout but does not move the position of the layout on the paper.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: Didn't know that package yet. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me like a bug in the code. The package switches to twoside within the calculations for the `layout=a5paper`but neglects to move the whole  area within the paper area as well (which it should in that case, I would say).

So I guess the answer is to do this manually:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\hcorr
\setlength\hcorr{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\hcorr{-\Gm@layoutwidth}
\makeatother

\geometry{layouthoffset=.5\hcorr,
          layoutvoffset=1in}
```

The value of `\Gm@layoutwidth` is simply the internal width calculated by the `layout=` key or specified by `layoutwidth=`. The assumption is that `\paperwidth` minus that length divided by 2 puts our page smack in the middle horizonatally. And the `layoutvhoffset=1in`is just there to move the top cropmark  onto the paper, you may not want that.

Comment: +1 and accepted: It solves the problem, thank you! (And you explain why/how it works.) I'll file a bug report. Moving the top cropmark onto the paper is a good idea, I think, because now all four sides are treated in the same way. As you can see from my posted figure, at the one page the line of the top cropmark is visible and at the other one it is not, and cutting away just some pt of paper is probably difficult, while 1in should be easy.

Comment: @Stephen I'm in contact with Hideo and he intends to look into it.

Comment: After some years, any new way to handle this without hacking?