# How to set up two-sided geometry for physical cropping of just two edges?

Tags: geometry, crop

I'm trying to print a two-sided document on physical paper that is too large, which I will then cut to its final dimensions.  I wish to cut each sheet of paper just twice, so I am trying to place all the excess space on the *outer* and *lower* edges of the sheet.  I have tried the `geometry` package alone and also the `crop` package (together with `geometry`, as recommended).  In both cases, I can get the crop marks in the right place relative to the text, but I can't get the text in the right place on the physical page.

Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,layoutsize={3in,5in},body={2.5in,4.5in},
            left=0.2in,top=0.2in,twoside,showcrop]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

I have placed the PDF for this example at https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/mwe-geo.pdf.  On page 1, the text hugs the left-hand edge of the sheet, as desired.  But on page 2, the text *also* hugs the left-hand edge, where what I wish is for it to hug the right-hand edge.  In other words, when I cut the waste off of page 1, I want also to be cutting the waste off of page 2, which is printed on the flip side of the same sheet.

How can I get the even-numbered pages offset so that the waste falls in the right place for physical cutting?

Comment: I notice that if you remove the `layoutsize` option, then things work as you want.  I don't know why, because I'm not an expert.

Comment: @James interesting.  Unfortunately that loses the crop marks.  But if I have to dive into the code, your observation will be useful!

Comment: See the following question.  It suggests that you have found a bug.  It also appears to offer a work-around.  Good luck!  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45283

Comment: @James I should have mentioned I already found that answer.  It "fixes" the problem by shifting all the text toward the center.  Not what I hoped for.

Comment: You might look at `zwpagelayout`. It gets the reflection right on odd/even pages, but I can't immediately figure out how to make it work for a 1-up layout rather than 2-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack that works when using the `geometry` package together with `crop`---but not with `geometry` alone.  I adjust `\evensidemargin`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[papersize={3in,5in},body={2.5in,4.5in},
            left=0.2in,top=0.2in,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,letter,odd]{crop}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\evensidemargin+\stockwidth-\paperwidth}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The geometry package is not the only way to draw crop marks.  (Don't forget to run this twice.)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,body={2.5in,4.5in},
            left=0.2in,top=0.2in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AddEverypageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \ifodd\value{page}\draw
    (current page.north west) ++(3in,-5in) ++(0.25in,0) -- ++(0.5in,0)
    (current page.north west) ++(3in,-5in) ++(0,-0.25in) -- ++(0,-0.5in);
  \else\draw
    (current page.north east) ++(-3in,-5in) ++(-0.25in,0) -- ++(-0.5in,0)
    (current page.north east) ++(-3in,-5in) ++(0,-0.25in) -- ++(0,-0.5in);
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \ifodd\value{page}\draw
    (current page.north west) ++(3in,-5in) ++(0.25in,0) -- ++(0.5in,0)
    (current page.north west) ++(3in,-5in) ++(0,-0.25in) -- ++(0,-0.5in);
  \else\draw
    (current page.north east) ++(-3in,-5in) ++(-0.25in,0) -- ++(-0.5in,0)
    (current page.north east) ++(-3in,-5in) ++(0,-0.25in) -- ++(0,-0.5in);
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice, but OP might need to do some tweaking of dimensions.  Currently, the crop marks will lead to cutting off the page numbers.

Comment: @James - The old crop marks were the same.  Since there is only 0.3in left on the bottom, [footskip=0.2in] would be a good idea.